# Can I buy a Portuguese train ticket that is not bound to a specific train?

Tags: trains, portugal

I'm travelling from Lisboa Oriente to Guarda next week.  I hope to catch the 13:39 direct train, but I'm not sure if I can make it. There is a later, indirect and slower connection departing 14:09 (that I can certainly catch, but I would much prefer the 13:39 connection).

The terms and conditions state that *The tickets are personal and unalienable and they are only valid for the days and trains mentioned on them.* Is there any way I can buy a ticket *in advance* that is valid for either connection? I may be short on time to buy a ticket on the station (I have a meeting near the airport that finishes 20 minutes before the 13:39 departure). I may be able to get to the station the day before.

Comment: Buy two tickets? :)

Comment: @JonathanReez: I don't think "two tickets" is a valid suggestion when the question asks for "a ticket" ;)

Comment: @JonathanReez That has no advantage over buying a ticket for the first train, and then if I miss it, buy a ticket for the second train instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tickets for Intercidades (IC) and Alfa (A) are specific to a train, thay even come with your seat information.
Tickets for Regional (R) can be used in any train (in same day).

Both your options involve IC or A, so you cannot opt for another train after you buy your ticket.

My experience is that in these hours in working days trains usually have seats available until the departing hour, so **if you can take some risks** I would advise you to buy your ticket once you get to the train station (although queues may require you to be there 15m before timetable).

Comment: Hmm. If I buy a ticket for the 13:39 IC 513 Lisboa Oriente – Guarda, and miss it, I would instead take 14:09 AP to Coimbra for which I need a new ticket, but can I still use my other ticket for the R5408 from Coimbra to Guarda…?  Perhaps I will just play confused foreigner and see how far I get (or perhaps I will make it to the 13:39).

Comment: I guess so. Intercidades is above Regional in termos of quality and price so I guess the ticket will be accepted for R5408 without complains (and if you have to justify, as a confused foreigner you won't have much troubles ahah).